# Need better way to sort&merge multi-dimentional array

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Since I have to analysis huge data which contain multi-dimentional arrays,
I need to sort them well.
However, it's quite complicated in this time. 
Multi-dimentional arrays of coordinates ordered un-continuous way.
no certain length, flag on the both end.
I made an simple example below; **testarr**
Actually, I tried my cord below and it worked. but I think there must be better way for this.
If you willing to do so, please let me know better solution.

```
testarr = [["Z",33,34,35,36,"END"],["A",1,2,3,4,5,"B"],["C",8,9,10,"D"],["B",6,7,"C"],["G",27,28,29,30,31,32,"Z"],["D",11,12,13,14,"E"],["begin",-10,-5,0,"A"],["F",19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,"G"],["E",15,16,17,18,"F"]]

def sortingAS(tararr):
    temparr = []
    for i in tararr:
        if not temparr:
            temparr.append(i)
            continue
        checker = True
        for j in temparr:
            if j[0]==i[-1]:
                j.pop(0)
                temparr.append(i+j)
                temparr.remove(j)
                checker = False
                break
            if j[-1]==i[0]:
                i.pop(0)
                temparr.append(j+i)
                temparr.remove(j)
                checker = False
                break
        if checker:
            temparr.append(i)
        #print(temparr)
    return temparr

def sortingMain(target):
    toreturn = sortingAS(target)
    if len(toreturn)>1:
        toreturn = sortingMain(toreturn)
    return toreturn

resforme = sortingMain(testarr)
print(resforme)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the you want to sort the array introducing a combined ordering of the elements (taking into account first and the last element of the list). My suggestion is to use the `sort` method with `key` argument:

```
testarr_sorted = testarr.sort(key=lambda vv: v[0], v[-1])
```

In this way you disregard all of the numerical values and take into account only the strings in the following order: the first elements are compared and if they are equal only then the last items are compared for alphabetical order and sorted appropriately.

In case you wanted something slightly different you can change it following the pattern I suggested.

Comment: Very appreciated for your suggestion. I didn't know that the "sort" can help me even on this case. I'm gonna try this. Thank you.